# How can I pass arguments in the terminal command line using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, linux, terminal

I wrote a program in JS that reads an input file, needs k value, and writes the result in an output file. I would like to know how I can run the program through the terminal and enter the input file, k value, and output file's name in the command line?
Like the following command line:
I want to pass my arguments here in the command line.(The input file name goes to xyz, and the output file name goes to abc)
node filename.js "input=xyz.txt; k=3 ;output= abc.txt"

Answer (score 0):

The `process.argv` properties should help you achieve that, although it won't be reading inputs and writing outputs out of the box (you have to write your own code to do that). I recommend you to take a look at [this blog post](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/) at the official node.js site.